# Elixir - Nested JSON parsing to structs

Tags: json, elixir

Disclaimer: I've checked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142735/map-a-nested-json-payload-to-a-struct-in-elixir) and it does not answer mine.

I am trying to come up with a way for nested struct parsing of JSONs. Example:

```
{"name": "blah blah", "address": {"street": "smthing"}}
```

I want to reach this result:

```
%User{name: "blah blah", address: %Address{street: "smthing"}}
```

Because then it would be easier to plug validation (using [Vex](https://github.com/CargoSense/vex) for exapmle).

I know that Poison supports the "as struct" option but it does not provide nesting. The above would be parsed:

```
%User{name: "blah blah", address: %{"street" => "smthing"}}.
```

I know I could write a decoder implementation for module `User` but I guess that is not the intended use case and it would not be generic.

When wondering about an implementation I could not find a way to tell if an atom is a module... maybe I have to go with `:code.is_loaded(module_name)`?

Anyway, before trying an implementation I would like to know if there is something I am not seeing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the above is now possible with Poison:

```
defmodule User do
  @derive [Poison.Encoder]
  defstruct [:address]
end

defmodule Address do
  @derive [Poison.Encoder]
  defstruct [:street]
end

Poison.decode(response, as: %User{address: %Address{}})
```

Comment: This works great for me with Poison 2.0. Thanks @Maikon

Comment: This is solid gold, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the only option that I am aware of is to provide your own implementation for the `Poison.Decoder` (note the trailing `r`) protocol. This has the added benefit that you can have these conversions in one place and just need to write `as: User` to get the address converted properly. For example:

```
defimpl Poison.Decoder, for: User do
  def decode(task_list, options) do
    Map.update! task_list, :address, fn address ->
      Poison.Decode.decode(address, Keyword.merge(options, as: [Address]))
    end
  end
end
```

Note that the inner call to `decode` is not from `Poison.Decoder`, but  **`Poison.Decode`**, without the trailing `r` in the module name. You will not get an error if you do use the wrong one, it just won't work, which can be a pain to debug.

In the long run, I think a bit of work needs to be done in Poison to make all of this more fun to use. Maybe a macro that will make it easier to write `Poison.Decoder` implementations for custom structs. Maybe also support for nested struct options like `as: %User{address: Address}`, that should not be too hard to implement. Also I think the module names `Decode` and `Decoder` are too easy to confuse and one of them should be renamed. If I have the time, maybe I will make those suggestions and set up a PR with Poison.

Comment: If I go that way maybe a more generic approach is to implement a generic decoder that I would `use BaseDecoder` and then inside `def __using__(_), do: etc` to define an implementation for the protocol. But then I would have to know if an atom is a valid module that is a struct.

Comment: I personally think that's a bit too much magic, but hey, why not ;-) Certainly this setup could be simplified, but i'd prefer a more explicit approach. I've opened a Github issue for this, let's see what the original author thinks and then maybe I'll try to implement it. https://github.com/devinus/poison/issues/35